# Get SVN revision number to batch file variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn

Want to get last changed revision from svn branch in batch file.

```
echo on
set svnUrl=%1
set releaseName=%2
set buildNumber=%3


for /f %%i in ('svn info  %svnUrl%/branches/%releaseName% -r HEAD ^| FINDSTR "^Last.Changed.Rev:"') do set revisionNumber=%%i
echo %revisionNumber%
```

But I'm getting word Last instead of Last Changed Rev: 10

In console for command

```
D:\svn info http://desktop-24i22vk:81/svn/Test/branches/TST-1 -r HEAD
```

I'm receiving console output:

```
Path: TST-1
URL: http://desktop-24i22vk:81/svn/Test/branches/TST-1
Relative URL: ^/branches/TST-1
Repository Root: http://desktop-24i22vk:81/svn/Test
Repository UUID: 57a8baac-304e-e54b-94b3-b7d049dce932
Revision: 17
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: import
Last Changed Rev: 10
Last Changed Date: 2016-07-22 15:26:37 +0200 (pá, 22 čvc 2016)
```

I want to get last changed revision number, here it's 10. I was thinking to store whole line text Last Changed Rev: 10 to variable and then replace text to get only number. I would appreciate even other (windows batch) approaches how to get it.
Thanks

Comment: See [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) syntax: `for /f "tokens=4" %%i in .....`

Comment: Thanks, great solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of FOR /F is to break each line into tokens, delimited by spaces and/or tabs, and return only the first token of each line. That explains why you are only getting "Last".

You could preserve the entire line by setting the delims option to nothing

```
for /f "delims=" %%i ...
```

But you don't want the entire line. You just want the last (4th) token. So ...

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%i ...
```

Answer (score 2):

May use
`svn info -r HEAD --show-item revision`
to get ONLY the Head rev as output...